# svg-image shown wrong in IE11

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer, svg

I have a svg-file on my page that is shown correctly in every other recent browser but IE11.

If I open the image itself in IE it's shown correctly, but embedded in the page as an image there are two problems which may or may not have the same reason - and hopefully solution.

The svg contains a rectangle and text. I'm using svg instead of css, because it is supposed to be scaling with the pagesize and I need the stable aspect ratio. Here we are, problem #1: The image doesn't scale in IE. Why?

```
HTML: <img id="sprocket" src="sprocket1.svg"/>
CSS: #sprocket {margin: 10% 0% 10% 62%; width: 33%; min-width: 40px;}
```

Problem #2: The text is not "in" the rectangle (again only in IE when embedded in the page like this) but next to it to the right. Strange? The distance between them gets smaller when I scale down the window.

Note: I found a slightly similar question where the IE modulation for some reason chose an older browserversion. I already checked this.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle of your relevant code where you use the real image? Problem #2: What text are you referring to?